# Long running kiosk application eats up memory without freeing it

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, performance, ram, swap

I've a long running application built with PHP/HTML/CSS3/JS running on Chrome on a Ubuntu Server 14.04.03. I've set everything up to make it work and let it run for some days.

I've noticed something very disturbing, when I first launch the kiosk the memory usage is around 400MB but as the application runs longer the memory usage increases. It's currently running for about 22 hours and the memory usage is at 1400MB(!). The computer that runs it has 4GB of RAM so it seems like everything is fine for now. When it will reach the 4000MB mark, it will start swapping and my application is basically dead.

The Kiosk is running on Chrome version 45. How can I clean up the memory usage and free all available memory?

Answer (score 0):

The memory is not "available", it has been allocated for use by a program. These programs are called "memory hogs". Use commands like `top` and `ps -eF` (and, of course `man top;man ps`) to see which program has the most memory allocated. Then, fix that program.

Comment: as I stated in my question, the program that takes all that memory is Google Chrome. The "program" that runs on chrome is a HTML/CSS/JS/PHP one. It just keeps on "taking" more RAM without freeing anything. The chrome process started with 400MB of ram usage and by now it is already at 1500MB. I just want to know if there is somewhat a way to free that RAM and return is to the way it was at the beginning where is consumed 400MB of RAM only

Comment: So, your question really is "How can I periodically make chrome do a garbage collection"

Comment: if this is what it takes to free the unused memory that chrome keeps without releasing, then yes, I would like to know how to periodically make chrome do a garbage collection.  If there is a way to manually run the GC I can do that and report of the memory usage after doing it so we can see if it's really the solution

Comment: I googled "How can I periodically make chrome do a garbage collection", and part way down the results page found this link: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/profile-performance/memory-problems/memory-diagnosis?hl=en